# jQuery match multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup, and I want to make the `All` radio button checked.

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" value="All" name="Foo"/>All</li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="New" name="Foo"/>New</li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="Removed" name="Foo"/>Removed</li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="Updated" name="Foo"/>Updated</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to match via attribute, but I need to match on 2 attributes, `@name='Foo'` and `@value='All'`.

Something like this:

```
$("input[@name='Foo' @value='all']").attr('checked','checked');
```

Can someone show how this can be done?

Comment: The XPath syntax for arguments (using "@") has been deprecated in jQuery 1.2.6 and removed from jQuery 1.3. The CSS syntax is now the only available syntax ("[attribute=value]")

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The following HTML file shows how you can do this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(event){
          $("input[name='Foo'][value='All']").attr('checked','checked');
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio"  value="All"  name="Foo"  />All</li>
      <li><input type="radio"  value="New"  name="Foo"  />New</li>
      <li><input type="radio"  value="Removed"  name="Foo"  />Removed</li>
      <li><input type="radio"  value="Updated"  name="Foo"  />Updated</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="" >Click here</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you click on the link, the desired radio button is selected.  The important line is the one setting the `checked` attribute.

Comment: Why the attributeEndsWith selector (name$) instead of just attributeEquals?
To the OP - note that @ in front of attributes has been deprecated.

Comment: @MarkBrackett - it was lifted from some similar code of mine which had lots of similarly named unnumbered-list groups and I'd done the lot with one statement.

I copied the code in but didn't edit that bit, so I'll change it now - thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 15):

I was beating my head against a wall similar to this and just want to point out that in jQuery 1.3 the syntax used in the accepted answer is the ONLY syntax that will work. The questioner uses the @ syntax for the expression which does not work at all in jQuery. Hopefully this helps the next guy to come across this question via Google =p

To be clear, you have to use

```
jQuery('input[name=field1][val=checked]')
```

and not

```
jQuery('input[@name=field1][@val=checked]')
```

Comment: Thanks - the @ will trip up an unwary xpather like myself.