# How do I select elements on multiple attribute values

Tags: jquery

With jQuery, it is easy to select elements with a given attribute value.

For example:

```
var elements = $('div[attr1="value1"]');
```

But how do I select on multiple attributes (e.g., `attr1 = value1` ***and*** `attr2 = value2`)?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155977/jquery-match-multiple-attributes

Comment: Helpful document about [Multiple Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

Answer (score 117):

Since jquery uses CSS selectors, as defined by the CSS specification a selector with multiple conditions will look like:

```
$('div[attr1="value1"][attr2="value2"]')
```

see the CSS spec for further reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: where exactly did you get that idea?  I cited the exact place in the documentation that supports my statement.  If you are going to refute what I said (and vote me down), I would at least expect a courtesy of a reference to something official.

Comment: I tried your code in my project and found it not working. I did it practically and don't have any other reference.

Comment: $('div[attr1="value1"]').filter('div[attr2="value2"]'); this code works like charm.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: So in 7 years, 31,000 views and 59 upvotes, you are the first one to say this answer is wrong.  Can you explain?

Comment: jQuery documentation says clearly "Matches elements that match all of the specified attribute filters" so yes it is an AND and not an OR and this is the correct answer. https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 22):

You could for example chain and filter like so

```
var elements = $('div[attr1="value1"]').filter('div[attr2="value2"]');
```

Answer (score 16):

Find this solution quite simple.

```
$('[attr1="home"][attr2="settings"]')
```

Comment: @DanielLiuzzi above is correct for performing AND

Comment: @Geek It wasn't correct when I added my comment. Seeing that the answer has since been edited and fixed, I'll delete the comment to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple attributes, see the code below.

This code will find all inputs that have an `id` attribute and whose name attribute ends with 'man' and sets the value.

```
$( "input[id][name$='man']" ).val( "this input has id and name ends with 'man'" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even target an element like so:

```
const elem = $('.className[type="checkbox"][name="someName"]')
```

or in more dynamic way with a parameter:

```
const elem = $('.elemClassName_'+$(this).data('id')+'[type="checkbox"][name="someName"]')
```

I use the last example to target a checkbox when an input value changes.
The above is from many examples, and they work for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you use with space it takes child

```
$("#a .b")  = <div id="a"><div class="b">..
```

If you use without space it take same object with 2 class

```
$("#a.b")  = <div id="a" class="b">..
```