# Changing the div using class and data-index attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <div class="my_class" data-index=0></div>
 <div class="my_class" data-index=1></div>
 <div class="my_class" data-index=2></div> 
 <div class="my_class" data-index=3></div> 
 <div class="my_class" data-index=4></div>
```

How to change the css properties of a div having class `my_class` and the `data-index=0` using jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select elements by data attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)

Comment: see this : [how-do-i-select-elements-on-multiple-attribute-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045071/how-do-i-select-elements-on-multiple-attribute-valueshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045071/how-do-i-select-elements-on-multiple-attribute-values)

Answer (score 3):

Query for class and [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
$('.my_class[data-index=0]').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_class" data-index=0>1</div>
 <div class="my_class" data-index=1>2</div>
 <div class="my_class" data-index=2>3</div> 
 <div class="my_class" data-index=3>4</div> 
 <div class="my_class" data-index=4>5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("[data-index=0]").css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_class" data-index=0>Test</div>
 <div class="my_class" data-index=1>Test</div>
 <div class="my_class" data-index=2>Test</div> 
 <div class="my_class" data-index=3>Test</div> 
 <div class="my_class" data-index=4>Test</div>
```