# Bootstrap Table filter using hide/show?

Tags: jquery

I'm using to filter the records of a table the show/hide option with jquery.

```
$("tbody tr[data-ediction!='"+ed+"']").hide();
$("tbody tr[data-ediction='"+ed+"']").show();
```

In the `<tr>` I add the data-edition and it value.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Did you mean multiple attributes? If so, then you can try `tr[data-ediction!='" + ed + "'][data-yourcustomattribute1='" + customValue + "'][data-etc='" + customEtc + '"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery match multiple attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155977/jquery-match-multiple-attributes)

Comment: one you should mark as answer if it works for you, second don't change you question completely to new topic and third this edit is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var ed=1;

  $("tr[data-ediction='"+ed+"'][color='red']").hide();
 $("tr[data-ediction='2']").show();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr  data-ediction='1'>
    <td>Jill-show</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr   data-ediction='1'>
    <td>Eve--show</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  color='red' data-ediction='1'>
    <td>Jill--hide</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  data-ediction='2'>
    <td>Eve--show</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```